# Prime ideal and maximal ideal of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In an integral domain, $\{0\}$ is always a prime ideal. What about maximal ideal? $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is an I.D but it is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$. So I can not conclude that $(0)$ is always maximal ideal in I.D, right? Then what about an example of ideal which is prime in $\mathbb{R}$ ( real numbers) but not maximal?
As every field is an integral domain, can I conclude that $(0)$ is not always maximal ideal of field?

Comment: Waiting for suitable answer.

Comment: If you have questions on my answer, you are welcome to post comments. It is indeed a complete answer to your question, however, so I'm not sure what you mean by 'suitable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. You can see in many books related to the topic ( *Atiyah-Macdonald*, 1.2 **and if you want more expression,** Lemma 3.1 of the book *Steps in Commutative Algebra* by *Sharp* ):

> $R$ is a field if and only if $R$ has exactly two ideals: $0$ and $R$ itself.

Case 1. $R$ is a field. (e.g $\mathbb{R}$)
In this case $0$ is the only proper ideal (Hence maximal ideal) of $R$.

Case 2. The domain $R$ is not a field.
In this case $R$ has an ideal other than $0$, say $I$. Since $0\subsetneq I$, you know that $0$ is not maximal.

Comment: Alex Wertheim 's answer is complete and **suitable** +1. but i add references with a little more expression.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks for fleshing out my hints.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: what are the ideals in a field? More generally, do you know the fact that for any commutative ring $R$ and ideal $I$, $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is maximal?

Comment: This statement is correct for commutative rings with 1, but not for arbitrary rings.

Comment: @Loic: yes. I've made this explicit in my answer now. (For me, ring always refers to ring with unity; like many others, I call a ring without $1$ a 'rng'.)